# How can I send a hashtable to my clientsocket?

Tags: java, sockets, hashtable

I'm currently working on a small chat program, and for my next step I would like to send a hashtable to my clients, from my server.

However, so far I was using

`PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());`

in my Server class, and

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
```

in my Client class, which were used to transport messages in form of strings from both sockets to the respective other end of the connection.

This does not work for Hashtables anymore, considering they are no primitive datatype.

What would I have to use instead to be able to send my Hashtable fully working to my client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Hashtable` implements the `java.io.Serializable` interface, you can serialize the object and send it over the socket's output stream:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable(); // TODO: avoid raw types
...
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(table);
oos.close();
```

To read the object in the client, you need to use an `ObjectInputStream`:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
Hashtable table = (Hashtable) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: Is the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream a better option for sending strings as well?

Comment: No, they are suitable only for sending complex objects.